# Information theory - Intuition of the formula of code rate

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

I'm reading *Elements of Information Theory* - 2nd edition (2006). In the book, at page 195, they give the formula:

> The *rate* $R$ of an $(M, n)$ code is
>
> $\hspace{5.0cm} R = \frac{\log M}{n}$ bits per transmission

The definition of an $(M, n)$ code is given as

> An $(M, n)$ code for the channel $(\cal{X}, p(y|x), \cal{Y})$ consists of the following:
>
> 1. An index set $\{1, 2, ..., M\}$ (i.e. indices of possible messages)
> 2. An encoding function $X^n: \{1, 2, ..., M\} \to \cal{X}^n$, yielding codewords $x^n(1), ..., x^n(M)$. The set of codewords is called the *code-book*
> 3. A decoding function
>
> $\hspace{5.0cm} g: {\cal{Y}}^n \to \{1, 2, ..., M\}$,
>
> which is a deterministic rule that assigns a guess to each possible received vector

According to CMU documents, the messages $m$ passing to $X^n$ comes from a compressor, which compresses messages coming from source (i.e. source coding). Given this assumption, I cannot find any intuitive understanding about the code rate formula.

According to some other document, the message $m$ passing to $X^n$ comes from some information source (i.e. $m$ is the original message that hasn't been compressed yet). Given this assumption, I understand the formula $R = \frac{\log M}{n}$ as:

- The information source use $\log M$ bits to represent each possible message $m$ within the set of possible messages $\{1, 2, ..., M\}$ (i.e. the naive way of representing symbols, used in ASCII)
- Since each message from $\{1, 2, ..., M\}$ is represented using a string $S$ of $n$ symbols from $\cal{X}$

$\hspace{1.0cm} \rightarrow R = \frac{\log M}{n}$ can be understood as the average number of bits, in the original message, that each of the symbols in $S$ is responsible for representing.

Is my understanding correct ? If not, please give me some explanation of the formula $R = \frac{\log M}{n}$

Comment: Note that these are closely related, and the second interpretation also makes sense for the first. Why? Suppose you indeed had a source coder in front of the channel. Then by the usual typicality arguments, and because of asymptotic equipartition, the output of the source coder is an approximately uniform random variable supported on $\approx 2^{m H(S)} =: M$ symbols, (contd.)

Comment: where $m$ is the blocklength of the source code (the number of source symbols it encodes together). So, for the channel encoder, whether it receives an input from a uniform distribution on $M$ symbols or the output of a source coder of blocklength $m$ and entropy $H(S)$ makes no difference. Indeed, given some limitations, it would not be able to distinguish these situations (in a loose sense, this is part of why the source-channel separation theorem holds).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw, I've read thoroughly the book and they silently define $m$ as coming from source, not from any compressor